# How to design a system that stretches input by factor of 2?

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, impulse-response

In general, How do we design a system that takes input x(t) and outputs x(t/2)? I know that if system outputs x(t/2) then the frequency domain of output signal has the form X(2f). But what should be the impulse response for such systems?

Comment: hmmm stupid question, if this is  [tag:continuous-signal] continuous time, how are you physically dealing with the fact that with 1 hour of input, you produce 2 hours of output? You don't have a time machine… So you can't actually design a system like that. You can do theoretical considerations, but you can't build it. Or is this not actually time-continuous, and you're in the (imho) easier case of discrete-time signals?

Comment: In both cases, you need unbounded memory, don't you?

Comment: The red-shift (doppler) of stars that for the foreseeable future moving away from us would seem to satisfy this question (with the exception that the scaling probably is 1.000001 rather than 2)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller if not practically, I wonder if it is possible to make such a system in theory? And yes the input is continuous time.

Comment: @user133933 not at all. you can't say "make" and "in theory"; that's just a paradox, unless you state which axioms you are willing to ignore.

Comment: @user133933 we might be able to help you much much better if you actually told us *where* this question arose, *why* you're asking it. You're a bit in danger of having an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: (I mean, maybe I should be spelling this out: you can have a continuous-time recording, for example audio as magnetic field intensity on a magnetic tape, e.g. a music cassette, and play it back at twice the speed. But you get the problem I mentioned in the first comment: you do the recording for 1 hour, but your system produces two hours of output, that's a bit problematic if you want to model the system. It of course works – it's just not a TI system anymore, and it's either not causal or you need infinite tape)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I get it now. So any system that's y(t) = x(at) where a is not 1 is a time variant system. So it's not possible to model such a system with impulse response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what should be the impulse response for such systems?

There is non. It's not an LTI system and hence it can't be described by it's transfer function or impulse response.

Of course there are time-stretchers or compressors in (for example) audio. They typically look for snippets of the signal that are more or less periodic and then cut out or replicate entire periods. The details there depend a lot on the type of signal and what your specific requirements are.